# I planted bell peppers. Is this actually a bell pepper?

Tags: vegetables, bell-peppers

I planted a bunch of different things. Bell peppers, squash, etc.

The bell pepper plants are all about the same size (10").
One grow on the very far side right next to where I started growing broccoli.

I fear it's not actually a bell pepper plant. It's about 4ft tall and has a ton of seeds blooming off of it. It has a stalk and leaves just like bell pepper plants I've googled, but I don't see anything that resembles what this is turning into.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI5rV.jpg

[image]

Comment: Voted to close because image isn't in question.

Comment: Oh how funny!  This looks like POKEWEED.  We just had a question about a plant that looks just like this.  Go check it out...!!  "Leafy plant with small pink flowers"...a newbie plant for me but can't believe to see another possibly of the same!

Comment: @blackthumb the files are >2mb and uploading as an imgur album is easier than individually.

Comment: @stormy after googling it i'm positive that's what it is. Should i just yank it out?

Comment: you can still provide a link to the image, which I saw you now did.

Comment: yes, take it out, it is, indeed, pokeweed...

Comment: @blackthumb the link was always there. Pulling it out now.

Comment: The tiny plants to the left of the pokeweed are peppers, except for one of them right next to it.